# Magento 2 UI Component Image upload form in admin

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, model

controller `Upload.php` file.

```
namespace Dac\Recipes\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;


use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class Upload
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * Upload constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Dac\Recipes\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }

    /**
     * Check admin permissions for this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Dac_Recipes::recipe');
    }

    /**
     * Upload file controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('recipes');

            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }

        // print_r($result); die('upload controller');

        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

and add save controller file.

```
<?php

namespace Dac\Recipes\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;
//namespace Dac\Recipes\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Dac_Recipes::recipes';
    protected $dataProcessor;
    protected $dataPersistor;
    protected $imageUploader;


    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        PostDataProcessor $dataProcessor,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
    )
    {
        $this->dataProcessor = $dataProcessor;
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();


        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($data) {


            if (isset($data['recipes_image'][0]['name']) && isset($data['recipes_image'][0]['tmp_name'])) {
                $data['image'] = $data['recipes_image'][0]['name'];
                $this->imageUploader = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                    'Dac\Recipes\RecipesImageUpload'
                );
                $this->imageUploader->moveFileFromTmp($data['image']);
            } elseif (isset($data['recipes_image'][0]['image']) && !isset($data['recipes_image'][0]['tmp_name'])) {
                $data['image'] = $data['recipes_image'][0]['image'];
            } else {
                $data['image'] = null;
            }


            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }
    }
//    public function execute(){
//        die('save image');
//    }
}
```

di.xml config file.

```
<virtualType name="Dac\Recipes\RecipesImageUpload" type="Dac\Recipes\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">test/tmp</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">test</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Dac\Recipes\Controller\Adminhtml\Test\Upload">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Dac\Recipes\RecipesImageUpload</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Model file.

```
   <?php

namespace Dac\Recipes\Model;

/**
 * Catalog image uploader
 */
class ImageUploader
{
    /**
     * Core file storage database
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
     */
    protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;

    /**
     * Media directory object (writable).
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * Uploader factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
     */
    private $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * Base tmp path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseTmpPath;

    /**
     * Base path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $basePath;

    /**
     * Allowed extensions
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $allowedExtensions;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        $baseTmpPath,
        $basePath,
        $allowedExtensions
    ) {
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Set base tmp path
     *
     * @param string $baseTmpPath
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath)
    {
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Set base path
     *
     * @param string $basePath
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBasePath($basePath)
    {
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowed extensions
     *
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
    {
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base tmp path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseTmpPath()
    {
        return $this->baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBasePath()
    {
        return $this->basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return $this->allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFilePath($path, $imageName)
    {
        return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
    }

    /**
     * Checking file for moving and move it
     *
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $basePath = $this->getBasePath();

        $baseImagePath = $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName);
        $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);
//        echo 'sdfdsfsdfss'; die('move file');
        try {
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
            );
        }

        return $imageName;
    }


    public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
//        print_r($baseTmpPath); die();
        $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);

        $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));

        if (!$result) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
            );
        }

//        $seatch=' \ ';
//        $subject='/';
//        die($result);
        $result['tmp_name'] =str_replace("\ ", "/", $result['tmp_name']);

        $result['path'] = str_replace('\ ', '/', $result['path']);
        $result['url'] = $this->storeManager
                ->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
        $result['name'] = $result['file'];

        if (isset($result['file'])) {
            try {
                $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
                $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
                );
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

admin form

```
<field name="recipes_image">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">recipe</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
            <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Dac_Recipes/image-preview</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="recipes/test/upload"/>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Not working in upload File getting the error

Attention

The file was not uploaded.

Comment: You got any solution for this issue, im also getting same error

Answer (score 1):

add image-preview.html page in web/template

```
<div class="file-uploader-summary">
    <div class="file-uploader-preview">
        <a attr="href: $parent.getFilePreview($file)" target="_blank">
            <img
                    class="preview-image"
                    tabindex="0"
                    event="load: $parent.onPreviewLoad.bind($parent)"
                    attr="
                    src: $parent.getFilePreview($file),
                    alt: $file.name">
        </a>

        <div class="actions">
            <button
                    type="button"
                    class="action-remove"
                    data-role="delete-button"
                    attr="title: $t('Delete image')"
                    click="$parent.removeFile.bind($parent, $file)">
                <span translate="'Delete image'"/>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="file-uploader-filename" text="$file.name"/>
    <div class="file-uploader-meta">
        <text args="$file.previewWidth"/>x<text args="$file.previewHeight"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and get file name on the controller

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
$recipes_image= $data['recipe']['recipes_image'][0]['name'];
```